# Choosing low-pass filter parameters

Tags: matlab, filters

I have position of objects from recording sampled at 30 fps. I wish to remove high frequencies from position with the help of low-pass filter.

I am confused as to how to choose the filter parameters in this respect->

```
[b,a] = butter(n,Wn)
```

that is , `n` and `Wn` in this case.

Data:

```
K>> [xcor_i,ycor_i ]

ans =

 -101.7000  -77.4040
 -102.4200  -77.4040
 -103.6600  -77.4040
 -103.9300  -76.6720
 -103.9900  -76.5130
 -104.0000  -76.4780
 -105.0800  -76.4710
 -106.0400  -77.5660
 -106.2500  -77.8050
 -106.2900  -77.8570
 -106.3000  -77.8680
 -106.3000  -77.8710
 -107.7500  -78.9680
 -108.0600  -79.2070
 -108.1200  -79.2590
 -109.9500  -80.3680
 -111.4200  -80.6090
 -112.8200  -81.7590
 -113.8500  -82.3750
 -115.1500  -83.2410
 -116.1500  -83.4290
 -116.3700  -83.8360
 -117.5000  -84.2910
 -117.7400  -84.3890
 -118.8800  -84.7770
 -119.8400  -85.2270
 -121.1400  -85.3250
 -123.2200  -84.9800
 -125.4700  -85.2710
 -127.0400  -85.7000
 -128.8200  -85.7930
 -130.6500  -85.8130
 -132.4900  -85.8180
 -134.3300  -86.5500
 -136.1700  -87.0760
 -137.6500  -86.0920
 -138.6900  -86.9760
 -140.3600  -87.9000
 -142.1600  -88.4660
 -144.7200  -89.3210
```

Code:

```
[b,a] = butter(6,0.6,'low');
dataOut_x = filter(b,a,xcor_i);
dataOut_y = filter(b,a,ycor_i);

K>> plot(xcor_i,ycor_i,'Linewidth',2 );
K>> hold on
K>> plot(dataOut_x,dataOut_y,'Linewidth',2)
```

[image]

Clearly, my parameters aren't correct.

Moe info:
I have tried a simple moving average, doesn't work that well. I am recording people from an overheard camera. I have tracks of each's head using some software. I want to periodicity from tracks due to head wobbling.

Link to same question on stackoverflow: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616131/choosing-low-pass-filter-parameters?noredirect=1#comment56979276_34616131

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that the filters start with an initial position of `(0,0)`. Then when you filter your actual data, the filter output has to ramp up to the actual position. In doing so, you can also observe some overshoot since your filter has a very short time response.

It would help if you were to start with a better estimate of the initial position by using for example the first position with:

```
dataOut_x = xcor_i(1)+filter(b,a,xcor_i-xcor_i(1));
dataOut_y = ycor_i(1)+filter(b,a,ycor_i-ycor_i(1));
```

The resulting plot would then look like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What parameters a and b did you choose? I am confused over parameters -I have sampling rate of 30fps and human can change direction every 0.5 secs. What could be the cut-off frequency and order.

Comment: I used the same parameter for `a` & `b` as you used for this plot. For smoother results you could go down to a cutoff of about 2Hz (related to your 0.5 secs update), which would mean `Wn = 2/(0.5*30fps) ~ 0.13`.

Comment: Thanks again! Can you provide more details as how you calculated that cut-off frequency and also how I could decide a good estimate for the order parameter.

Comment: The parameter `Wn` is a normalized frequency in terms of the Nyquist frequency, which is half of your 30fps sampling rate (ie. 15fps). So if you want to keep 2 updates per second content, a good starting starting value of `Wn` is 2/15. As for the order parameter, it should generally be the smallest order which satisfies your requirements (which you haven't specified).

Comment: By requirements you mean. Can you provide an example please if possible.

Comment: By requirements I mean if you have some specific noise rejection criteria (eg. if you have known interference at a specific frequency, how much movement in the smoothed data does your application tolerate from frame to frame, ...). You might also want to have a look at this tutorial: http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_8.html.

Comment: Thanks so much! Would it be also possible to ensure that the starting and the ending point are the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33875/discussion-between-sleutheye-and-abhishek-bhatia).